# Piet Mondrian style painting using Turtle graphics and recursion

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

My Python exercise states the following:

> The twentieth-century Dutch artist Piet Mondrian developed a style of abstract
> painting that exhibited simple recursive patterns. To generate such a pattern
> with a computer, one would begin with a filled rectangle in a random color and
> then repeatedly fill two unequal subdivisions with random colors, as shown in
> Figure 7-16.

[image: Generating a simple recursive pattern in the style of Piet Mondrian]

> 

As you can see, the algorithm continues the process of subdivision until an “aesthetically
right moment” is reached. In this version, the algorithm divides the
current rectangle into portions representing 1/3 and 2/3 of its area and alternates
these subdivisions along the horizontal and vertical axes. Design, implement, and
test a script that uses a recursive function to draw these patterns.

> 

Now here is my code attempting to do this:

```
from turtle import Turtle, tracer, update
from random import randint

count = 0
posTest = 0
def draw(t, length, width, step, level):
    global count, posTest
    
    if level == 0:#base case
        t.fillcolor(randint(0,255),randint(0,255),randint(0,255))
        t.begin_fill()
        #being calculations
        t.forward(step)
        t.forward(length)
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(width)
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(length)
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(width)
        t.right(90)
        
        t.end_fill()
        if posTest % 2 == 1:#if it's 2nd box, move to pos for next iteration
            t.forward(length)
            t.right(90)#length becomes width here
            
        posTest += 1

    else: # two calls for 2 more rectangles
        if count % 2 == 0:
            draw(t, length*(1/3), width, 0, level-1)
            draw(t, length*(2/3), width, length*(1/3), level-1)
            count += 1
        else:
            draw(t, width*(1/3), length, 0, level-1)#flip width and height
            draw(t, width*(2/3), length, width*(1/3), level-1)
            count += 1
            

def main():
    t = Turtle()
    #tracer(False)
    #grid.draw_grid(10,-200,200,-100,100)
    update()
    length = 400
    width = length//2
    level = 2
    step = 0
    t.up()
    t.goto(-.5*length,.5*width)
    t.down()
    draw(t,length,width, step, level)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Let's assume I'm setting `level = 2`. My code basically draws 2 rectangles side by side for each pass of the else statement:

`else: # two calls for 2 more rectangles`

One rectangle is 1/3 the length, and one is 2/3 the length. After each of these cycles, the turtle goes to the end of the rectangle using the `step` value and turns and gets ready for the next iteration. Here is that part of the code, which is controlled by the variable posTest:

```
if posTest % 2 == 1:#if it's 2nd box, move to pos for next iteration
            t.forward(length)
            t.right(90)#length becomes width here
```

The turtle's new direction has the affect of changing the length and the width for the next draw calls in the nested else statement, so I flip the arguments around here:

```
else:
    draw(t, width*(1/3), length, 0, level-1)#flip width and height
    draw(t, width*(2/3), length, width*(1/3), level-1)
    count += 1
```

The problem is, anything greater than level 1 shrinks the rectangle from the desirable size of

```
length = 400
width = 200
```

At `level = 0` and `level = 1` the size and output are correct, but at `level=2` the rectangle shrinks, and anything greater than `level =2` produces a wrong result.

Here is a picture of my results for levels 0-3:

[image: Levels 0-3]

Just to note, I'm not trying to split each of the first two rectangles into 4 rectangles as shown in the level 2 picture in the problem's description. I'm assuming that would need 2 turtles or more complex code.

I'm simply trying to split the larger of the 2 rectangles created into two smaller rectangles, and repeating this process, but alternating the chops horizontally and vertically. For example, with my level 1 picture, the working area from that point should just be that red box.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mondrian Art Program Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36435261/mondrian-art-program-python)